# Replace quotes (but not touch nested quotes)

Tags: javascript, regex

Got problems with next issue:
I need to replace quotes with angle quotes, but if sentence got quotes again - the shouldnt be replaced.

So to get open quote I use next:

```
const regexStartQuote = /"(?=\S)/gm;
const replaceStartQuote = '«'
```

to replace quote with closing one I use:

```
// const regexEndQuote = /(?<=\S)"/gm; // not supported in Mozilla
const regexEndQuote = /"(?=\s)/gm;
const replaceEndQuote = '»'
```

And this works. I mean:
"Some text" -> «Some text»

Btw I work with draftjs and this changes applied on fly.

And I need to extend existing regex`s so if the sentence should be something like:

**«Some text "Text in quotes" something more»**

And, of course possible variants like:

**«Some text "Text in quotes", something more»**

**«Some text: "Text in quotes", something more»**

**«Some text: "Text in quotes",- something more»**

**UPDATE**

The flow of program is next:
Each symbol that is typed is merged with string. I mean, first when e.g. textblock is empty

the string is just `` (empty),

then user type 'w' -> string become `w`,

then 'o' -> string `wo`,

then 'w' -> string is `wow`,

then ' ' (space) -> string is `wow`,

then `"` -> string is `wow «`

and so on

As I understand, regex should be something like:

`If user typed "  and there is no » before it but we have «  we shouldnt change ".

Comment: It seems to too complex (impossible?) to do when user is typing. You'd better check/replace the whole string when user ends typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This handles the nesting of quoted strings that occur on a line boundary (the quoted string itself does not have to *begin* and *end* at the *start* and *end* of the line). This is somewhat artificial, but if you want to allow for multiple internal quoted strings within the outer quoted string, then this almost becomes a necessity. This would be the problem. Consider the following string:

```
var s = '"This is an "internal quote" within a sentence." A short sentence.\n' +
        '"Another quoted sentence."\n' +
        '"Yet another quoted sentence."' +
        'etc.';
```

What prevents `" A short sentence.\n"`and `"\n"`, for example, from being recognized as internal quoted strings? In other words, it becomes impossible to tell when a quote signifies the end of the outer quoted string or the start of a new internal quoted string (at least until you get to the end of the entire input).

The regex: `^([^"\n]*)"((?:[^"\n]*"[^"\n]*")*[^"\n]*)"([^*\n]*)$`

1. `^` Matches the start of the line.
2. `([^"\n]*)` Capture group 1: 0 or more characters that match anything other than `"` or newline. This is everything on the line that might precede the opening quote.
3. `"` Matches the opening quote. Now we will be looking for optional quoted strings withing the outer quotes
4. `(?:[^"\n]*"[^"\n]*")` A non-capturing group that looks for 0 or more non-quote/non-newline characters followed by a quote followed by 0 or more non-quote/non-newline characters followed by a quote. This would be an internal quoted string.
5. `((?:[^"\n]*"[^"\n]*"))*` The above pattern can be repeated 0 or more times.
6. `[^"\n]*"` Matches 0 or more non-quote/non-newline characters followed by a quote. This takes care of matching the rest of the quoted string.
7. `([^*\n]*)` Matches the rest of the line (0 or more characters), which should not include a quote.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

The above regex is fairly complicated because it checks for balanced quotes. If you do not care to do such rigid checking, then a simpler regex that only looks for the first and last quotes on a line would be (and the rest of the code stays the same):

```
/^([^"\n]*)"([^\n]*)"([^"\n])*$/gm;
```

```js
var s = 'A plain line.\n' +
        'This is "Some text in quotes" and some without.\n' +
        '"This has "quotes within quotes" and some without."\n' +
        '"This has "many" "quoted" "strings" within quotes."'
        ;

var regex = /^([^"\n]*)"((?:[^"\n]*"[^"\n]*")*[^"\n]*)"([^*\n]*)$/gm;
console.log(s.replace(regex, "$1«$2»$3"));
```

**Update**

To modify input, `s`, as it is entered, you need to test against several regular expressions:

1. If input matches `/^[^"\n]*$/` (no quote on line), then no replacement necessary.
2. If input matches `/^[^«\n]*«([^»\n]*»)?[^"\n]*$/`, then no replacement necessary.
3. If input matches `/^([^"«\n]*)"$/` (first quote seen), then `s = s.replace('"', '«');`
4. If input matches `/^([^"«\n]*)«([^\n]*)"$/` (other than first quote seen), then `s = s.replace('»', '"'); s = s.replace(/"$/, '»');`

Code snippets don't seem to allow true one-character-at-a-time input, but this one simulates what it would look like:

```js
function test(str)
{
    let s = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        key = str.charAt(i);

        s += key;
        if (/^[^"\n]*$/.test(s) || /^[^«\n]*«([^»\n]*»)?[^"\n]*$/.test(s))
            ;
        else if (/^([^"«\n]*)"$/.test(s))
            s = s.replace('"', '«');
        else if (/^([^"«\n]*)«([^\n]*)"$/.test(s)) {
            s = s.replace('»', '"');
            s = s.replace(/"$/, '»');
        }
       console.log("\n" + s);
    }

}

test('a"bc"de"fg"h"ij"');
```

Comment: Thanks, update the questions by adding the flow of execution.

Comment: thanks for the answer.. the main issue that result always change.. in update I try explain the flow

Comment: @WannaBeBetter I am not sure what else you want. I also added a simpler regex that is not as rigid (it accepts unbalanced quotes such as `"This is "unbalanced."`).

Comment: @WannaBeBetter I've shown how to handle one-character-at-a-time input. I am **DONE**.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
const startRegex = /^"/gm;
const endRegex = /"$/gm;

str.replace(startRegex, "<<")

str.replace(endRegex, ">>")
```

```js
const startRegex = /^"/gm;
const endRegex = /"$/gm;
const str = `"Some text "Text in quotes" something more"`

let result = str.replace(startRegex, "<<")
result = result.replace(endRegex, ">>")

console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but there is problem with closing angle quote:
«text "dsf" adsfsdfdsf"

Comment: In case that changes applied online $ seems to be unusable because of ;literally you are always in the end of the string...

Comment: can you please add some example string.

Comment: Thanks, update the questions by adding the flow of execution.